# adding a success page in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to add a success page with a message after a user has successfully filled a form. One way I can do it is by making new components for every success page I have, but this can add a lot of, not so useful, components. Is there any other way I can do that and I want to dedicate an entire page for the success message and not display a popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using a service. Added this in the service

```
getSuccessDetail(info: string) {
  if (info === 'cardApplication') {
    this.message = 'Customer Successfully Registered!';
  }
  if (info === 'addBank') {
    this.message = 'Bank Successfully Added to your Account!';
  }
  if (info === 'addFunds') {
    this.message = 'Funds Successfully Added to your Account!';
  }
}
```

And called the service from a component

```
export class CardApplicationComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private serverService: ServerService,
          private router: Router) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onCardSubmit() {
    this.serverService.getSuccessDetail('cardApplication');
    this.router.navigate(['/success']);
  }
}
```

Used the message property in the service to display in the SuccessComponent  template.

Thank you Everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a SuccessMessageComponent that has your generic success message (or if you want to customize it, then add an input parameter). Then add it to a route like '/success' and when you want to display the success message just redirect the users to this route.

Comment: But what if I want to have different success messages like "Successfully Registered" or "Successfully Logged In"?

Comment: Humm I see your point... You could use a router parameter but it wouldn't look great. Here's some info on this: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html

Comment: Pass message as @Input for your successfull component